# Subversion concept : svn update or svn info

Tags: svn

ok, here my point, i have a working copy of a svn on a server that must be kept up to date. so i setup a cronjob to update the svn very often. my script just make an svn update at a specific interval of times. i try to use the post-commit hook script on the svn server but did not succeed.

anyway, my boss ask me to modify the script to make a svn info, and compare the current rev with the rev of the working copy and then if there is a change, then trigger the update.
he think that the server load on the svn server will be less that making an update at the same time interval. my tought is that svn update surely does compare but version before updating.

i don't have any problem in doing the svn info script but i don't think it will change anything.

i look for information about svn update and what it really does, but did not find something helpful.

edit: @Wrikken and @Ben, first of all let me clarify my environement.
my svn environement is on lan only so we use svn protocol (svn://). my svn server is an ubuntu server and my client is a debian server. i already have hookscript configure and working on my svn server to sync with a third server that are a mirror of my svn server. my svn server work with user svn. my hook script and my script are own by the same user (svn). here is my post-commit script (the svnsync command work fine)
    #!/bin/sh

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
ME=`whoami`

echo "post-commit $REPOS $REV user: $ME " >> /var/log/svnsync.log

# non interactive:
/usr/bin/svnsync sync --non-interactive svn://path/to/mirror/repository --username "user" --password "######" >> /var/log/svnsync.log 2>&1
/path/to/script/script.sh >> /var/log/svnimpact.log 2>&1
```

now here my script that connect and update the working copy on my second server (its only an svn client not an svn server)

```
#! /bin/sh
/usr/bin/sshpass -p "######" /usr/bin/ssh svn@ipaddress 'svn update /path/to/working/copy'
```

executing only the update script work fine with the same user that run the svn server (svn)
but its never been execute when a commit is done. 
i'm kind of lost now.

Comment: `svn info` & then a `svn update` is heavier on the server then just a `svn update`, which doesn't really do much if there's nothing to update. I'm curious what problems you ran into with the post-commit hook, works perfectly here to trigger builds....

Comment: @Wrikken Finaly we find our problems. the svn user never does a ssh connect on that server before. so, with the sshpass command it was given the password to the question did you trust the computer. so the command never properly work. we change the post-commit to use a ssh key instead and everything start working has it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be clear `svn info` only talks to the server if you specify a URL or a specific revision.  To do what you're describing specifying a specific revision would be counter productive, so you'd need to be specifying a URL.  Otherwise you're only going to get the info as is stored locally from the last update.

When `svn info` needs to go the server it needs to retrieve some property data in order to provide you the output it provides in the output of info.  If you're doing this over HTTP it's going to do some OPTIONS and PROPFIND requests.

When you do a `svn update` the client makes an update-report request.  In doing so it sends a description of the state of the working copy (in your case you're probably going to have a whole working copy at a single revision which makes the requst fairly simple) and then the server responds to the request by describing how to transform the data the client has in the working copy into the requested version (or HEAD if no version was specified).  In order to do this over HTTP the client makes some OPTIONS and REPORT requests (the 2nd report request is to support inherited properties).  Depending on the client and server it may need to do additional requests to fill in some details.  E.G. newer servers don't send the actual file deltas in the REPORT response but instead specify the URLs to request them (allows these deltas to be cached).

Now to your question, is it worth making an `svn info` request before `svn update`?  I doubt it.  The work the server has to do in order to respond to the PROPFIND requests is very similar to what it needs to do in order to respond to the REPORT requests.  It ends up having to do the work twice since between your info and update requests there could have been a commit.  I'd put this in the same category as people who run stat on a file before opening it.

There are however better solutions to the problem that you're raising.  Wrikken suggested using a post-commit hook to trigger the update.  That's certainly one option, though that means the server hosting Subversion has to have some way to communicate to the server you're trying to run update on.  Most of the time people do this by allowing the Subversion server ssh access to other machines.  Which may be undesirable for security reasons.

Rather than rolling your own way to handle that communication or dealing with the security complications of allowing the Subversion server access to the machine you want to runthe update on you can use svnwcsub with a svnpubsub server.  You can find both of these tools in the [tools/server-side/svnpubsub](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/branches/1.8.x/tools/server-side/svnpubsub/) directory of the Subversion 1.8.x tarballs.  svnpubsub is a server that distributes commit notifications to clients that subscribe to them.  svnpubsub receives the notifications from a post-commit hook named commit-hook.py.  svnwcsub is a client of svnpubsub that subscribes to the server side and automatically updates working copies as configured when an update happens that would impact them.

Once you have a svnpubsub infrastructure you can do all sorts of things.  There's some code there to subscribe to the updates and then tweet on commit or send a message to an irker (IRC bot).

Comment: _"don't use a post-commit hook, use a ... post-commit hook!"_ :P (But I get your point, indeed, giving SSH access is a bit to much, enough other mechanisms available. Never worked with `svnpubsub` as I never needed more then 1 thing listening, whipped up some quick custom service normally, but I'll check it out ;) )

Comment: Well it's not so much as avoiding the post-commit as avoiding having to bother to write your own custom service to allow for the privilege separation.